# Where can one find information about damping coefficients for electronic transitions in atoms?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, refraction, absorption

I understand that the index of refraction for a given atomic species with number density $N$ near a single electronic transition associated with frequency $\omega_0$ given by
$$
n(N,\omega)=1+\frac{Nq_e^2}{2m_e\epsilon_0}\frac{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)f}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+\gamma^2\omega^2}
$$
where $f$ is the oscillator strength and $\gamma$ is the damping coefficient. I am interested in using this formula, but am having trouble tracking down values for $\gamma$. Is there some reason that these are more difficult to find than oscillator strengths, or are they expressible in terms of other quantities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This NIST webpage contains spectroscopic information for different atoms. In the advanced settings there is an option to show $f_{ik}$, the oscillator strength as a measure of the transition strength (note there are alternative quantities which capture similar information).

https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html

For example, I often work with the Rb D2 transition at 780 nm. I can see by looking it up [here](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/lines1.pl?spectra=Rb%200&limits_type=0&low_w=700&upp_w=900&unit=1&de=0&format=0&line_out=0&en_unit=0&output=0&bibrefs=1&page_size=15&show_obs_wl=1&show_calc_wl=1&unc_out=1&order_out=0&max_low_enrg=&show_av=2&max_upp_enrg=&tsb_value=0&min_str=&A_out=0&f_out=on&intens_out=on&max_str=&allowed_out=1&forbid_out=1&min_accur=&min_intens=&conf_out=on&term_out=on&enrg_out=on&J_out=on&submit=Retrieve%20Data) that $f = 0.695$ for this transition. The next strongest transition is the D1 transition at 795 with a oscillator strength $f=0.342$. These are the two brightest lines if you perform spectroscopy of Rb, that is why that got to be named lines historically, D1 and D2. We also see that the oscillator strengths add up to about 1 as predicted by the Thomas Reiche Kuhn sum rule.

Note I was confused about the notation. Apparently Rb I refers to neutral Rb. rather than singly ionized Rb.

It is difficult to theoretically calculate oscillator strengths because it has to do with fine details of the shape of the electronic cloud for the two states involved including higher order couplings I believe. It can of course be done in some cases but this is not my field so I can't say more about it.

Oh sorry, I've done a very bad job answering your question because I skimmed it too quickly. You're asking about $\gamma$ vs $f$. They are very closely related and you can derive one from the other. In fact, typically the formula you are showing only includes one of them since it is a bother to think about two constants that are just related to each other by a constant. Here's the formula from [Quantum and Atom Optics](http://atomoptics-nas.uoregon.edu/~dsteck/teaching/quantum-optics/) by Steck, a great reference on some of this atomic physics stuff. See Sec 1.2.1 on Oscillator strength

$$f_{0j} = \frac{2\pi \epsilon_0 m c^3 \gamma_j}{e^2 \omega_{j0}^2} \frac{g_j}{g_0}$$

$\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space, $m$ is the mass of an electron, $c$ is the speed of light, $\gamma_j$ is the linewidth or decay constant of the transition in mind, $e$ is the electron charge, $\omega_{j0}$ is the frequency of the transition. $g_j$ is the degeneracy of the excited state and $g_0$ is the degeneracy of the ground state. Set $g_j=g_0=1$ for a simple two level model.